# Improving performance on PostgreSQL for PowerBI Direct Query usage

Tags: postgresql, azure, architecture, powerbi, analytics

I'm trying to improve performance of a reporting solution I'm building. The tech I'm using is:

- Custom build Python tool extracting data and storing it in
- Azure Hosted PostgreSQL running GP compute with 8vCores
- PowerBI Desktop -> intention is to publish on app.powerbi.com

Data is extracted in JSON format and stored in two column tables (id::bigint, document::json). Then transformed into multi-column using views which have 1-to-many relationships between them based on ids.

Problem is one of the tables has ~4.5M rows and every time I do an action in Power BI it takes 5+ minutes for the database to process the request. By action I'm doing really simple operations: adding a column to a report using a single view (with 4M+ entries) as data source.

I've tried the obvious of adding more compute to my database, but got minimal improvement.
Beforehand I tried using ElasticSearch for storing data and found it difficult to integrate with Power BI and operate large sets of data.

Any suggestions what I should be looking at?

Later Edit - query I'm running:

```
EXPLAIN(ANALYZE,VERBOSE,BUFFERS)
SELECT DISTINCT PROJECTS.ID,
    PROJECTS.NAME,
    PROJECTS.WEB_URL,
    USERS.NAME AS OWNER_NAME,
    USERS.EMAIL AS OWNER_EMAIL,
    JOBS.USER_NAME AS JOB_USER_NAME,
    JOBS.USER_EMAIL AS JOB_USER_EMAIL
FROM "some sch".PROJECTS AS PROJECTS
LEFT JOIN "some sch".USERS AS USERS ON PROJECTS.CREATOR_USER_ID = USERS.ID
LEFT JOIN "some sch".JOBS AS JOBS ON PROJECTS.ID = JOBS.PROJECT_ID
WHERE PROJECTS.ID = 706
    OR PROJECTS.ID = 2319
    OR PROJECTS.ID = 13118
    OR PROJECTS.ID = 5201
    OR PROJECTS.ID = 8049
    OR PROJECTS.ID = 8091;
```

With the Query Plan:

```
"  Output: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, ((users.document ->> 'name'::text)), ((users.document ->> 'email'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'author_name'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'committer_email'::text))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=2696055 dirtied=3763"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1216639.41..1216984.48 rows=138030 width=200) (actual time=369683.465..369683.815 rows=13024 loops=1)"
"        Output: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, ((users.document ->> 'name'::text)), ((users.document ->> 'email'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'author_name'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'committer_email'::text))"
"        Sort Key: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, ((users.document ->> 'name'::text)), ((users.document ->> 'email'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'author_name'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'committer_email'::text))"
"        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3792kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2696055 dirtied=3763"
"        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=4835.61..1197116.61 rows=138030 width=200) (actual time=81549.985..369663.270 rows=13024 loops=1)"
"              Output: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, ((users.document ->> 'name'::text)), ((users.document ->> 'email'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'author_name'::text)), (((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'committer_email'::text))"
"              Hash Cond: (((((jobs.document -> 'pipeline'::text) ->> 'project_id'::text))::bigint) = projects.id)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2696055 dirtied=3763"
"              ->  Index Scan using jobs_pkey on public.jobs  (cost=0.43..1127637.25 rows=4601009 width=427) (actual time=0.078..369088.748 rows=4725016 loops=1)"
"                    Output: jobs.id, NULL::bigint, (((jobs.document -> 'pipeline'::text) ->> 'project_id'::text))::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::text, NULL::text, NULL::text, NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::double precision, NULL::double precision, NULL::text, ((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'author_name'::text), ((jobs.document -> 'commit'::text) ->> 'committer_email'::text), NULL::text, NULL::text, NULL::boolean, NULL::boolean, NULL::text, NULL::text, NULL::text, NULL::boolean"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2695341 dirtied=3763"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=4835.11..4835.11 rows=6 width=136) (actual time=52.747..52.751 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                    Output: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, ((users.document ->> 'name'::text)), ((users.document ->> 'email'::text))"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=714"
"                    ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=15.70..4835.11 rows=6 width=136) (actual time=3.388..52.744 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                          Output: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, ((users.document ->> 'name'::text)), ((users.document ->> 'email'::text))"
"                          Merge Cond: (users.id = projects.creator_user_id)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=714"
"                          ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on public.users  (cost=0.29..4687.80 rows=10544 width=193) (actual time=0.042..51.642 rows=2318 loops=1)"
"                                Output: users.id, (users.document ->> 'name'::text), NULL::text, NULL::text, (users.document ->> 'email'::text), NULL::text, NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::boolean"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=678"
"                          ->  Sort  (cost=15.41..15.43 rows=6 width=80) (actual time=0.986..0.990 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                                Output: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, projects.creator_user_id"
"                                Sort Key: projects.creator_user_id"
"                                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=36"
"                                ->  Subquery Scan on projects  (cost=15.26..15.34 rows=6 width=80) (actual time=0.975..0.979 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                                      Output: projects.id, projects.name, projects.web_url, projects.creator_user_id"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=36"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=15.26..15.28 rows=6 width=537) (actual time=0.974..0.977 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                                            Output: projects_1.id, (((projects_1.document ->> 'creator_id'::text))::bigint), ((projects_1.document ->> 'name'::text)), NULL::text, NULL::text, ((projects_1.document ->> 'web_url'::text)), NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::bigint, NULL::boolean, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric"
"                                            Sort Key: projects_1.id"
"                                            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=36"
"                                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.projects projects_1  (cost=8.38..15.18 rows=6 width=537) (actual time=0.285..0.965 rows=6 loops=1)"
"                                                  Output: projects_1.id, ((projects_1.document ->> 'creator_id'::text))::bigint, (projects_1.document ->> 'name'::text), NULL::text, NULL::text, (projects_1.document ->> 'web_url'::text), NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::timestamp with time zone, NULL::bigint, NULL::boolean, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::bigint, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric, NULL::numeric"
"                                                  Recheck Cond: ((projects_1.id = 706) OR (projects_1.id = 2319) OR (projects_1.id = 13118) OR (projects_1.id = 5201) OR (projects_1.id = 8049) OR (projects_1.id = 8091))"
"                                                  Heap Blocks: exact=6"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=36"
"                                                  ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.38..8.38 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.033..0.035 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=12"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on projects_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (projects_1.id = 706)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on projects_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (projects_1.id = 2319)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on projects_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (projects_1.id = 13118)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on projects_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (projects_1.id = 5201)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on projects_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (projects_1.id = 8049)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"                                                        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on projects_pkey  (cost=0.00..1.40 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                                              Index Cond: (projects_1.id = 8091)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=2"
"Planning Time: 0.385 ms"
"Execution Time: 369688.318 ms"
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Step one would be the query plan: EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) _your_sql_statement_ ; We also need the DDL for the tables involved, including the indexes.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - thanks for offering to help. Did an addition to my original post. The table's are relatively simple. 1 primary key - ID and text columns. Some have secondary keys ie: project_id I use to create relationships.

Comment: I am little bit confused about the question, so the data are coming as json, and then transformed into relational data... so the execution plan you provided is for just querying the "ready" table right? In addition please provide the hardware specs of the machine or the instance you are executing (provide also ram and disk iops)....

Answer (score -2):

You face the biggest performance problem of PostGreSQL whose COUNT type queries are extremely slow compared to other RDBMSs.

Read the article I wrote about it which shows a gap at most 1500 times slower than Microsoft SQL Server and on average 114 times...

[PostGreSQL vs Microsoft SQL Server – Comparison part 2 : COUNT performances](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/)

The only way to improve performances of such queries is to create materialized views... PostGreSQL does not have vertical indexes (aka columnstore), nor data compression that are usually used for BI

Comment: How do you know this question is about counting records? I don't see any query at all.

Comment: Do you know some BI application that does no count ? Not me !

Comment: We do real time analytics on millions of users and have just a few milliseconds to come up with a result. Counting is one of the many things we do, and we have no issues with that. Database is about 5TB in size with 20 billion records. Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, they might be faster, but not a lot: We hardly spend a 30 milliseconds on a request.